# Why can't complete month in txt file?

Tags: autocompletion

Part of setting in my .vimrc.

```
cat .vimrc
autocmd FileType txt setlocal omnifunc=CompleteMonths 
fun! CompleteMonths(findstart, base)
  if a:findstart
    " locate the start of the word
    let line = getline('.')
    let start = col('.') - 1
    while start > 0 && line[start - 1] =~ '\a'
      let start -= 1
    endwhile
    return start
  else
    " find months matching with "a:base"
    let res = []
    for m in split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec")
      if m =~ '^' . a:base
    call add(res, m)
      endif
    endfor
    return res
  endif
endfun
```

Now edit a test.txt file in vim.
Input `J` and press `<c-x><c-o>` ,why no month complete menu pop up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your autocmd to

```
autocmd FileType text set omnifunc=CompleteMonths
```

The file type for `.txt` files is `text` not `txt` and `omnifunc` is already local to the buffer (see [`:h 'omnifunc'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27omnifunc%27))

You also need to make sure that you have a line like this in your vimrc to be sure that the filetype is set:

```
filetype plugin on
```

With these modifications on your vimrc, the completion works on my setup.